# CRAN policies writing a file with an R package

Tags: r, cran

I wrote the Package [NetExplorer](https://github.com/SebastianSosa/Network-Explorer) that creates a html file to visualize a network. The file was created in the user R library folder but this violates the CRAN Policies. I created the file in the TMPDIR whith the following command:

```
tempdir <- tempfile()
dir.create(tempdir)
tmpFile <- file.path(tempdir, "Net.html")
```

However, CRAN policies say that such usage should be cleaned up. How could I achieve that as without the created file the network cannot be visualized?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards

Comment: Create a temporary environment and store it there?

Comment: check packages quantmod or getBatchsymbols. These download data in tmp files in a tmp directory.

Comment: In getBatchsymbols they save the file but I can't see any clean up: https://github.com/msperlin/BatchGetSymbols/blob/master/R/myGetSymbols.R

Comment: In quantmod, file path and clean up are dependent on getSymbolsDB function arguments. I will try this, thank you : https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/blob/a2aad1693ad9f7f6642bee225e139454a6965750/R/attachSymbols.R

Comment: @NelsonGon This is what  I am doing but the issue is the cleaning part. Does this need to be done by the function or is it automatic once the R session is closed?

Comment: I think such questions are better asked at https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel

Comment: The cleanup doesn't have to happen in the function, but it needs to happen by the end of the example in the help page.  If that's impossible, then in your example, only create the tempfile when running interactively, using `if (interactive()) ...`, or set it as `\donttest{ ... }`.